# Why is Cycles causing this distortion in displacement of a cco node?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, displacement

This is a very simple two object seen.  I'm using CCO textures setup per there instruction.[image: With displacement attached] [image: displacement detached]

In eevee, it looks normal.  In cycles it looks normal in preview view, but in rendered view it looks distorted.  This happens in both 2.8 and 2.9.  The only thing that seam to fix it is detaching the displacement node.  It only seams to happen with this seen, or at least it hasn't been so bad as to engulf the other objects.

Thanks for the help. I think I did what you suggested. Even if I didn't it still looks better. I think. If nothing else I now know what to play with.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One solution is like you said to disconnect te dislacement node. The other better solution is that you mix your displacement node with your normal map. Add a bump node and set the distance to somewhere around 0.01. Once that is done, connect your displacement image texture (Without the displacement node in between) to the height input of the bump node. Connect the normal map with the normal input in the bump node and connect the bump node to the normal input in the Principled BSDF. The way you did it heavily displaces the whole mesh.

Extras: You can try to decrease the scale of the displacement map the way you connected to about 0.001 or something as an experiment.